# Android manifest with XML empty tags?

Tags: android

In the manifest of my app, activities are highlighted in yellow and indicated:

> XML tag has empty body
>
> Reports empty tag body. The validation works in XML/JSP/JSPX/HTML/XHTML file types

[image]

I'm looking for information, but do not quite understand the message refers.

I appreciate any help to know that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> XML tag has empty body

The refers to your `<activity>` tags as you are closing them with a `</activity>` instead of `<activity (rest of code here...) />`

Using an explicit `</activity>` implies there is a body to your `<activity>` such as in this example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Whereas you are wanting something along these lines:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

With the `/>` at the end to get rid of these warnings

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your activity body empty. This is not fatal error,just replace 
`></activity>` to `/>`

Answer (score 1):

In XML there are two types of tags **empty tag()** & **non-empty tags ( body )**
The warning due to your "   " tag having empty body do close it as below if body is empty.

```
<activity
    ...
 />
```